# Shell underlined with link or info box

Tags: linux, shell

On Gnome shell when you type links like `https://www.stackoverflow.com`, it's underlined and you can click it to open the link in a web browser.

How can we use `echo` to make underlined text, that when you hover over it, it shows a small box with text for maybe some information?

I just know how to underline: `echo -e "\033[4m Underlined text \033[0m"`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible from a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because terminal emulators all emulate dumb terminals from the 1970's that didn't have mice. So the special "escape codes" that tell the terminal [emulator] to make text brighter or underlined or whatever, don't contain a code for specifying "this is a clickable link", or "here's some hover text / tooltip to display if someone hovers their mouse pointer over this text".

Modern terminal emulators that let you click on URLs aren't being *told by the shell* that these are URLs. Nothing is sending escape codes to tell the terminal [emulator] that this should be treated like a clickable URL. Instead, the modern emulator is just watching the stream of text it's displaying, and looking for anything that looks like a URL, and making it clickable on its own accord.

One could imagine that someone could come up with a new anachronistic terminal type to "emulate", and as part of that create escape codes for things like hover text / tooltips, and then add support for that stuff in the rest of the terminal software infrastructure, like termcap/terminfo, the "curses" library, etc., and encourage other open source projects like `bash` and `zsh` and `emacs` and `vi` to support it, but I don't think anyone's done that.